# how to left text search in input after submit

Tags: html, input, submit

I have search input. When I write a number to find something (this is an HTTP request) I have some results but my number from input disappeared. How can I leave it?

```
     div class="control is-expanded">
          <input
            name="request_id"
            class="input"
            placeholder="Request ID"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="control">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button is-link" />
        </div>
```

The HTTP request in on the beckent, which I didnt write. I do only frontend. Can I change this or not?

Comment: Store input value in session or get post value and return again in form and set in value="<?php if($_SESSION['request_id']){ echo  $_SESSION['request_id']; } ?>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return saveComment();">
    <input type="text" name="request_id" class="input" placeholder="Request ID from Furia" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button is-link" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("request_id").value = localStorage.getItem("comment");

function saveComment() {
    var comment = document.getElementById("request_id").value;
    if (comment == "") {
        alert("Please enter a comment in first!");
        return false;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("comment", comment);
    alert("Your comment has been saved!");

    location.reload();
    return false;
}
```